# telebot inline buttons

Tags: python, telebot, inline

Я новичок и у меня есть вопрос. Мне нужно, чтобы после нажатия на встроенную кнопку осуществлялся переход в новый блок с новой встроенной кнопкой и... Вот мой код. Проблема в том, что обработчик не работает при нажатии на вторую кнопку, которую я создал в первом обработчике...

```
import telebot


from telebot import types

TOKEN = ''

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    kb = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    btn_types = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='label1', callback_data='btn_types')
    kb.add(btn_types)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "text",
                     reply_markup=kb)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True)
def check_callback_data(callback):
    if callback.message:
        if callback.data == 'btn_types':
            file = open('photo1.jpg', 'rb')
            kb = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
            btn_types1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='label1', callback_data='btn_types1')
            kb.add(btn_types1)
            bot.send_photo(callback.message.chat.id, file,'text',reply_markup=kb)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True)
def check_callback1_data(callback):
    if callback.message:
        if callback.data == 'btn_types1':
            file = open('photo2.jpg', 'rb')
            kb = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
            btn_types2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='label2', callback_data='btn_types2')
            kb.add(btn_types2)
            bot.send_photo(callback.message.chat.id, file,'text',
                           reply_markup=kb)
    


bot.infinity_polling()
```

Comment: На ruSO принято задавать вопросы на русском

Comment: понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Отредактировал Ваш код. Я объединил Ваши обработчики в один, конфликтов более быть не должно. Все  будет переходить, таким образом, как Вы и зададите в дальнейшем. На данный момент блоки переходят от 0 к 1, от 1 к 2 (но переход со второго блока еще на описан).

Вот код решения:

```python
import telebot
from telebot import types

API_TOKEN = '{Ваш токен}'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)

# Переместил Ваши кнопки и клавиатуры отдельно от кода.
kb = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
btn_types = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='label1', callback_data='btn_types')
kb.add(btn_types)

kb1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
btn_types1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='label1', callback_data='btn_types1')
kb1.add(btn_types1)

kb2 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
btn_types2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='label2', callback_data='btn_types2')
kb2.add(btn_types2)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "text", reply_markup=kb)
    
    
# Функция callback_query_handler вносится один раз для обработки всех событий
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def answer(call):
    if call.data == 'btn_types':
        file = open('photo1.jpg', 'rb')
        bot.send_photo(call.message.chat.id, file, 'text', reply_markup=kb1)
    elif call.data == 'btn_types1':
        file = open('photo2.jpg', 'rb')
        bot.send_photo(call.message.chat.id, file, 'text', reply_markup=kb2) # Переход дальше не настроен, вы можете ссылаться на свои дальнейшие блоки или же вернуться к главному меню.


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # schedule.every().day.at('22:11').do(send_message)
    # Thread(target=schedule_checker).start()
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Успехов :)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: В таком случае можете отметить ответ, как верный (нажав на галочку) :)